# How can i take one attribute of my model and put it in a option element attribute of a activeDropDownList?

Tags: yii

In de documentation for activeDropDownList() -> $htmlOptions says this: options: array, specifies additional attributes for each OPTION tag. The array keys must be the option values, and the array values are the extra OPTION tag attributes in the name-value pairs. For example,

> array(
>          'value1'=>array('disabled'=>true,'label'=>'value 1'),
>          'value2'=>array('label'=>'value 2'),
>      );

So it should be posible to do it. 
I have something like this:

```
<?php 
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->condition = "estado = 'activa'";
        $criteria->order = "fecha_inicio";
        echo $form->dropDownList($model,'salida', 
        CHtml::listData(Salida::model()->findAll($criteria), 'id', 'fecha_inicio', 'actividad.nombre'), 
        array('prompt'=>'-- Selecciona --',
                    'options' => array(
               '26'=>array('disabled'=>true,),
               '23'=>array('disabled'=>true,),
        ))
    );?>
```

The drop down it's generating correctly. How can do this for all option taking the value form  one model's field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out:

```
        $opciones = CHtml::listData(Salida::model()->findAll($criteria), 'id', 'precio'); 
        $opciones_f = array();
        foreach ($opciones as $id => $precio) {
            $opciones_f[$id] = array('data-precio'=>$precio);
        }
        echo $form->dropDownList($model,'salida', 
        CHtml::listData(Salida::model()->findAll($criteria), 'id', 'fecha_inicio', 'actividad.nombre'), 
        array('prompt'=>'-- Selecciona --','options' => $opciones_f,)
```